# What does it mean for a cone's point of origin to be included or excluded in the cone's area of effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, area-of-effect

As part of the definition of a cone spell in the handbook:

> A cone's point of origin is not included in the cone's area of effect, **unless you decide otherwise.**

As an example, what would either case be for a casting of Burning Hands?

Could the caster include themselves? or does this mean that they can exclude the first square of the cone?

Comment: Are you asking: Would a caster always burn themselves every time they cast Burning Hands??

Comment: Good question. I never thought of this after all my sorcerers.

Comment: @PJRZ I'm pretty sure the OP is asking what are the pros and cons of including the point of origin and possibly asking which square is the origin.

Comment: Somewhat related: "[cone point of origin for large creatures (i.e. when a dragon breathes)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95798)

Comment: @Eternallord66 I can already think of many pros and cons of including the caster. I'm moreso asking what exactly *is* this choice. What am I choosing between? Hitting the caster vs. not? Hitting the person in front of me or not?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## You can damage yourself, if you really like

The cone's point of origin is the square the caster is in, or if you're using more abstract ways of measuring, the point of origin is the caster themselves. (Their hands, their mouth, whatever the spell's flavour decides.)

> Spells that create [areas of effect] that originate from you also have a range of self, indicating that the origin point of the spell's effect must be you. (PHB p.202, emphasis mine.)

This rule allows you to include the origin of the cone (yourself) in the effect. This most likely doesn't ever really seem like a good idea unless there's a Swarm in your space, but in that case, you are allowed to include your own space in the effect, else you'd never be able to hit something inside your own space with a cone spell.

Comment: Agree, but wonder if the question has not been framed under the incorrect assumption that spell areas always have to 'fit' into 5' squares.

Comment: I think you need to support that a *point* of origin is actually/somehow an *entire square.* In particular the accepted answer [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48998) ends with discussion of two possible ideas about what a point or origin is.

Comment: @Medix2 That rule is not in the PHB, where did you find it?

Comment: @Medix2 That makes things even more complicated with the rule in question. What lies on that point that isn't included in the cone itself?

Comment: @Axoren: If i'm understanding your last question correctly, the answer is "you" (or possibly "your space").

Comment: @PJRZ By that same reasoning, would it include all the squares at that intersection? Earning the caster an extra 2-3 squares of cone?

Comment: @Medix2 Most cone spells, such as Burning Hands which the question posed, have a range of self (15 feet cone). So the origin is always the caster. If you're using a square based combat system, either the square you are on in its entirety is part of the AoE, or it isn't, there's no "this part is and that part isn't." once you include the point of origin.

Comment: @Axoren. Again - I don't know why you think the area is made up of squares. It is a cone. Even if you are using the optional (but probably common) battle-map system, the creatures affected are those whose squares overlap the cone, and then only squares more than half-covered. There is nothing to suggest all the non-overlapping squares around the origin point would be affected. The only exception is "your space" as explicitly stated

Comment: @Medix2 also "Every area of effect has a point of origin, a location from which the spell's energy erupts. The rules for each shape specify how you position it's point of origin. Typically, a point of origin is a point in space, but some spells have an area whose origin is a creature or an object." (PHB spellcasting > Casting a Spell > Areas of Effect)"

Comment: @Illustro I've removed my comments as there are least is now text supporting the answer.